# JSON - Grab Child Node's Information without Preferring(Selecting) the Child Node's Name

Tags: javascript, java, json, salesforce

I am looking to implement a logic to dynamically grab the child node's information in a JSON structure without actually preferring to the child node itself. Then, I will concatenate this information into an array structure. For example:

Current State:

```
{
 "Data": {
   "Person1": {
      "FirstName" : "John",
      "LastName"  : "Doe,
    },
   "Person2": {
      "FirstName" : "Jane",
      "LastName"  : "Doe",
    }
}
```

Future State:

```
{
 "Data": {
   [ 
    {
      "FirstName" : "John",
      "LastName"  : "Doe,
    },
    {
      "FirstName" : "Jane",
      "LastName"  : "Doe",
    }
   ]
}
```

The goal is to have a logic that would not prefer to the child node's name such as "Person1" or "Person2", since there can be hundred of "Person[nth number]" returned in the JSON. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am currently working with Javascript

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly you would like to transform the inner object to array by loosing the keys. So you need the object values only. Surprisingly js has `Object.values` what exactly doing this. e.g

```js
const data = {
 "Data": {
   "Person1": {
      "FirstName" : "John",
      "LastName"  : "Doe",
    },
   "Person2": {
      "FirstName" : "Jane",
      "LastName"  : "Doe",
    }
  }
};

data.Data = Object.values(data.Data);
```

Comment: This is great Zoltan, but would you happen to know the logic behind this Object.values function ?

Comment: See it at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values